# Awk add a variable to part of a column string

Tags: shell, csv, awk

### Objective

add "67" to column 1 of the output file with 67 being the variable ($iv) classified on the difference between 2 dates.

File1.csv

```
display,dc,client,20572431,5383594
display,dc,client,20589101,4932821
display,dc,client,23030494,4795549
display,dc,client,22973424,5844194
display,dc,client,21489000,4251031
display,dc,client,23150347,3123945
display,dc,client,23194965,2503875
display,dc,client,20578983,1522448
display,dc,client,22243554,920166
display,dc,client,20572149,118865
display,dc,client,23077785,28077
display,dc,client,21811100,5439
```

Current Output 3_file1.csv

```
BOB-UK-,display,dc,client,20572431,5383594,0.05,269.18
BOB-UK-,display,dc,client,20589101,4932821,0.05,246.641
BOB-UK-,display,dc,client,23030494,4795549,0.05,239.777
BOB-UK-,display,dc,client,22973424,5844194,0.05,292.21
BOB-UK-,display,dc,client,21489000,4251031,0.05,212.552
BOB-UK-,display,dc,client,23150347,3123945,0.05,156.197
BOB-UK-,display,dc,client,23194965,2503875,0.05,125.194
BOB-UK-,display,dc,client,20578983,1522448,0.05,76.1224
BOB-UK-,display,dc,client,22243554,920166,0.05,46.0083
BOB-UK-,display,dc,client,20572149,118865,0.05,5.94325
BOB-UK-,display,dc,client,23077785,28077,0.05,1.40385
BOB-UK-,display,dc,client,21811100,5439,0.05,0.27195
TOTAL,,,,,33430004,,1671.5
```

Desired Output 3_file1.csv

```
BOB-UK-67,display,dc,client,20572431,5383594,0.05,269.18
BOB-UK-67,display,dc,client,20589101,4932821,0.05,246.641
BOB-UK-67,display,dc,client,23030494,4795549,0.05,239.777
BOB-UK-67,display,dc,client,22973424,5844194,0.05,292.21
BOB-UK-67,display,dc,client,21489000,4251031,0.05,212.552
BOB-UK-67,display,dc,client,23150347,3123945,0.05,156.197
BOB-UK-67,display,dc,client,23194965,2503875,0.05,125.194
BOB-UK-67,display,dc,client,20578983,1522448,0.05,76.1224
BOB-UK-67,display,dc,client,22243554,920166,0.05,46.0083
BOB-UK-67,display,dc,client,20572149,118865,0.05,5.94325
BOB-UK-67,display,dc,client,23077785,28077,0.05,1.40385
BOB-UK-67,display,dc,client,21811100,5439,0.05,0.27195
TOTAL,,,,,33430004,,1671.5
```

### Current Code

```
#! bin/sh

set -eu

de=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y" -d "1 month ago")
ds="15-04-2014"
iv=$(awk -vdate1=$de -vdate2=$ds 'BEGIN{split(date1, A,"-");split(date2, B,"-");year_diff=A[3]-B[3];if(year_diff){months_diff=A[2] + 12 * year_diff - B[2] + 1;} else {months_diff=A[2]>B[2]?A[2]-B[2]+1:B[2]-A[2]+1};print months_diff}')



for f in $(find *.csv); do

    awk -F"," -v OFS=',' '{print "BOB-UK-"$iv,$0,0.05}' $f > "1_$f.csv" ##PROBLEM LINE##
    awk -F"," -v OFS=',' '{print $0,$6*$7/1000}' "1_$f.csv" > "2_$f.csv" ##calculate price
    awk -F"," -v OFS=',' '{print $0}; {sum+=$6}{sum2+=$8} END {print "TOTAL,,,,," (sum)",,"(sum2)}' "2_$f.csv" > "3_$f.csv" ##calculate total

done
```

### Issue

When I run the first awk line (Marked as "## PROBLEM LINE##") the loop doesn't change column $1 to include the "67"  after "BOB-UK-". This should be done with the `print "BOB-UK-"$iv` but instead it doesn't do anything. I suspect this is due to the way `print` works in `awk` but I haven't been able to work out a way to treat it within this row. Does anyone know if this is possible or do I need to create a new row to achieve this?

Comment: Good that you have shown what you have tried to solve your problem. If you explain it more clearly what you are looking for in description kind of(problem's description in detailed manner) then we will get better understanding of question and we may help better, kindly add more information in your question and let us know.

Comment: Also got that part like you have to read multiple `csv` files then you are taking dates differences but question is what should be the logic to get your expected output? And are you looking for saving the output into Input_file itself?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Apologies, I realised I mixed up the data set a bit. I've updated the post to include; the correct data, what I get, and what I'm trying to get - along with a more detailed explanation. Let me know if it makes sense now or if it's still unclear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the variable value to `awk`. `awk` does not inherit variables from the shell and does not expand `$variable` variables like shell. It is another tool with it's internal language.

```
awk -v iv="$iv" -F"," -v OFS=',' '{print "BOB-UK-"iv,$0,0.05}' "$f"
```

Tested in [repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/QuirkyEarnestDesignmethod) with the input provided.

> for f in $(find *.csv)

Is useless use of `find`, makes no sense, just

```
for f in *.csv
```

Also note that you are creating `1_$f.csv`, `2_$f.csv` and `3_$f.csv` files in the current directory in your loop, so the next time you run your script there will be 4 times more .csv files to iterate through. Dunno if that's relevant.

#### How `$iv` works in awk?

The `$<number>` is the field number `<number>` from the line in awk. So for example the `$1` is the first field of the line in awk. The `$2` is the second field. The `$0` is special and it is the whole line.

The `$iv` expands to `$` + the value of `iv`. So for example:

```
echo a b c | awk '{iv=2; print $iv}'
```

will output `b`, as the `$iv` expands to `$2` then `$2` expands to the second field from the input - ie. `b`.

Uninitialized variables in `awk` are initialized with `0`. So `$iv` is substituted for `$0` in your `awk` line, so it expands for the whole line.

Comment: your example spits out a syntax error for the`,` in `OFS=','`. It seems I had to remove this to then get the code to run but in doing so it causes my rows to merge and produce the following example `BOB-UK-67 display,dc,client,20572431,5383594 0.05`. Is there a reaason why the `OFS` is rejected as it seems to be needed in order to keep my columns in the correct locations, and prevent the merging.

Comment: Did you copy it _exactly_ as presented? Including all the `"`? Who "spits out the syntax error"? bash or awk (or other tool)? How does exactly the "syntax error" message look like? Please be specific, don't describe what happens, show what happens.

Comment: @El_Birdo there is no syntax error in the posted script, you either copy/pasted incorrectly or there's a syntax error (e.g. missing terminating quote) elsewhere in your shell script. Run it through http://www.shellcheck.net.

Comment: Apologies, your code works. The error appeared to be coming from an additional part of my script (not mentioned in the post) which I didn't think would impact it. Thanks for your help.